# How to connect to build-in web server on Aptana Studio from another machine

Tags: extjs, webserver, aptana3

I have a project written in ExtJS 4 and I run it as: Web Browser build-in Web Server
The project runs fine on that machine under the url: 127.0.0.1:8020/MyProject/index.html

Now, I'd like to access that url from another machine. i.e. using the ip address of the machine where Aptana resides

myIPaddress:8020/MyProject/index.html

but it can not find it. Is there some configuration that I could do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.

The problem is proxy server setting in my case.

I solved the problem by adding the 'myIPaddress' into the bypass list on network proxy setting window.